# GET and POST requests fail when going to my custom server

Tags: ios, swift, post, get, nsurl

I have a linux based node.js server running on BlueHost that I have configured to respond to basic GET and POST requests. I have tested these requests extensively in Postman and they all seem to work great. I figured the transition to doing these requests from an app would not be too difficult but I am currently unable to get either of them to work.

I am using boilerplate code based on this repository. As an example here is the code I am using for the get request

```
guard let url = URL(string: "publicIP/test") else { print("Invalid url"); return }

let session = URLSession.shared
session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    if let res = response {
        print(res)
    }

    if let d = data {
        print(d)
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: d, options: [])
            print(json)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            print("ERRORED")
        }
    }
}.resume()
```

This code works great for the `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users` endpoint however whenever I try substituting it with my public ip (just like in Postman) and I keep getting the following error.

```
2018-02-18 01:14:35.633518-0800 Application[1248:321560] Task <2E64810D-C10E-4D45-82F5-9C9E37A5FE54>.<1> finished with error - code: -1002
```

Keep in mind this information is not passed throughout the error parameter as "ERRORED" is not printed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add this to your info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
 <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
 <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Not sure if you know something I dont but those dont appear to be valid setting names for the info.plist. I currently have the "App Transport Security Settings" dictionary with element "Allow Arbitrary Loads" set to "YES"

Comment: try it that way and see

Comment: No such luck. Interestingly enough it appears the terms are aliases for each-other. If you try to add the NSAppTransportSecurity key it says it already exists. Same with the value inside of the dictionary. Fascinating

Answer (score 0):

That error should not be related to using HTTP instead of HTTPS. App Transport Security failures return error code -1022.

The error code -1002 indicates an invalid URL. Perhaps your HTTP file contains a structurally invalid URL (e.g. missing scheme, a scheme other than http/https, etc.)?

For additional debugging, set this environment variable

```
CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS=1
```

in your Xcode project and re-run the app. Once you know what URL is failing, the problem will likely become more obvious.

If it isn't, file a bug.

You can check the list of error code on below link

[Apple Documentation NSURLErrorDomain Error Codes List](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes)

Comment: The url is a public ip adress like 11.111.111.11 and if put in a web browzer it does take you to a message from the server. Is that a problem?

Comment: May be. can't predict what apple will think about!!  Did you checked URL structure? and did you get anything after trying that environmental variable?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not any of the example code but merely a misunderstanding of what a url string should look like. I figured that I would need to match the url of the webpage as shown in the address bar of my web-browser but that is not exactly true because http does not show even if it is a part of the address in chrome.

The solution was simply to prepend `http://` to the front of my url.